# How to visualize an R^3 -> R function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-visualization

I've got a function that assigns a real value to every point in space. How can I visualize it on some bounded volume?

Comment: Have a look at the [3D visualisation routines](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/f16-8867.html) avaiable in MATLAB, perhaps [`isosurface](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/isosurface.html) is what you wnat. You'll need to be more specific with you question if you want a specific answer.

Comment: @Chris: I'd like, for example, a function that puts dots in a rotatable figure, with the dots being colored according to some heat map and not connected with lines/surfaces. Is that specific enough?

Comment: To be clear, I want to visualize it at uniformly distributed points in a box. It's fine if the points are quite sparse, e.g. 20x20x20 points. I'm trying to get an understanding of how a family of functions works so that I can choose a good optimization method.

Comment: A simple `scatter3` might be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend Peter's suggestion in the comments ^^:

use [scatter3](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/scatter3.html) *with* setting the `cdata` parameter:

```
% generating some sample data
[x,y,z]=sphere(50);
x=x(:);y=y(:);z=z(:);

% the interesting stuff:
h=scatter3(x,y,z);
```

gives you

[image: scatter3]

To add coloring, do the following:

```
set(h,'cdata',z)
```

or immediately:

```
scatter3(x,y,z,'cdata',z);
```

which results in

[image]

Here the color vector is just the z value, but it can be anything (as long as it's the same size as x (and y and z).

Comment: Thanks! I did it this way with meshgrid.